# Doctrine 1.2: Can a model have two instances of the sluggabl behavior?

Tags: php, model, doctrine

I dont see any direct mention on using multiple slugs (or any behavior for that matter) for single model. Is there a way to use the sluggable behavior to generate two separate slugs for a model?

For example i need to generate two slugs for every record a `product_id` consisting of a slugified company name and sku and a `distributor_id` consisting of a different slugified company name.

Obviously i could write this myself fairly easily, im just wondering if this can be done quickly with Sluggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple slugs... read my answer for similar question: [Can a table have multiple slugs in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515236/can-a-table-have-multiple-slugs-in-doctrine/2526011#2526011)

Comment: Yeah looks like a manual definition is they way to go. Thanks.